# Inheritance and Threads to modify super values

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Vehicle extends Thread implements Serializable{

   private int gas; 

   public Vehicle(int gas){
       this.gas = gas;
   }
}//Vehicle

public class Car extends Vehicle{

   private int brakes;

   public Car(int fuel, int brakes){
       super(fuel)
       this.brakes = brakes;
   }

   @Override
   public void run(){
       //code here
   }
}//Car
```

My question is, since this is a Thread and I need to modify some values from the super class(the gas), is there any way to do it in the run method? As far as I know, the only way is making an instance but I can't do it there

The idea is to reduce the fuel level while the car is moving

As well, the serializable implement will work if I try to write a Car object into a file, or the car is the one that needs to extends from serializable?

This is just an example, I also have another class called Bus and both of them have different run methods, Just saving some code

Comment: As you have extended Vehicle class, the gas is automatically inherited but since it is a private member, you can implement the getter-setter method for that variable or else make it public variable.

Comment: Ok I understand it and it worked, I really had no idea about that, now the question will be about the serializable implementation

Comment: `Serializable` is what's sometimes referred to as a 'tag interface' and simply says the class is serializable. The serialization is either done automatically,  or by custom implementation via specific methods which are private (and thus not-inherited). Serialization is mildly magical and not a particularly useful way to reason about inheritance. You might want to consider using `Runnable` instead of inheriting from `Thread` since a vehicle probably isn't actually a thread.

Comment: For serialize implementation you can use **Synchronized Block** [javaTpoint Link](https://www.javatpoint.com/synchronized-block-example).

Put your sensitive code that can be used many times simultaneously into the synchronized{} block

Answer (score 0):

your variable in supper class is private so it is not visible to your child class.
If you make it protected then it will be visible.So you can change the value.
One more point I would suggest supply a protected synchronized method for multiple thread visibility and avoid race condition.If it is thread context specific and not modify by multiple thread then not required.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the code like, really sorry for the bad formatting.

1. Introduce a setter method for fuel in the vehicle class and invoke it from the sub class run method.
2. Can think about making the vehicle class Runnable, if you do not want to persist all the thread related information while serializing the objects.
3. In order to serialize the super class instance variables you have to mark the Vehicle class implements serializable.

   public class Vehicle implements Serializable 
   {
   private int fuel;

   ```
      public Vehicle(int fuel){
          this.fuel = fuel;
      }

   protected void setFuel (int fuel){
       this.fuel = fuel;
   }
   ```

   }//Vehicle

   Now car extends vehicle and implements Runnable

   public class Car extends Vehicle implements Runnable{

   private int brakes;

   ```
      public Car(int fuel, int brakes){
          super(fuel)
          this.brakes = brakes;
      }

      @Override
      public void run(){
          //code here
          setFuel(fuel-1); // update the fuel value
      }
   }//Car
   ```

There is a nice and crisp explanation about serialization in this question.

[Are static variables serialized in Serialization process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000975/are-static-variables-serialized-in-serialization-process)