# Include class(static) variables in to JSON return

Tags: json, spring-boot, serialization, static

When response returns an object from spring-boot, JSON contains all object attributes but, class variables are not available. How can i return static attributes too in the return json??

example class :

```
public class classA{
    private static int var;
    private string name;
    private string address;
}
```

JSON returns as :

```
{ name : "", address : ""}
```

---

I require, the return to be :

```
{var : "", name : "", address : ""}
```

Comment: Also i am interested to know , how to return a static class with all static attributes without initializing an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Static variables are not serialized**, So during deserialization static variable value will loaded from the class.(Current value will be loaded.)

Refer : [are-static-variables-serialized-in-serialization-process?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16477421/6572971)

Comment: Isn't their any way to map static variables to to normal variables at run time?

Comment: No. Static variables can not be serialised.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I tried a different way to do this and succeeded. I post it here if anyone requires. Solution is to create custom serializer for the Class.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
public class classA{
    public static int var;
    private string name;
    private string address;
}

public class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name",((A)o).getName());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("address",((A)o).getAddress());
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("var",A.var);
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```